# Proper usage of Webform 6.x + webform_validation 2.x with conditional statements

Tags: 9, webforms

I'm on Drupal 9.4 with webform 6.x. The webform validation module is a bit confusing and I couldn't get the conditional statements to work properly. Below is my configuration. I have a hidden field and I want to populate this field with the duration the user is on the page when 5 seconds has passed with 5000 for milliseconds. From there I want to setup a webform condition to see if the number in this field is greater than 1000, if so it should submit the form, otherwise throw an error.

What is wrong with my condition?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like honeypot but with extra steps. This module will do what you're trying to achieve I think? https://www.drupal.org/project/honeypot (spam protection using a timer between page load and form submission) Have you considered using that if that's the case?

Comment: i would rather not install another module if possible.